# Only load ListFragment once via AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to learn Android development and am still trying to wrap my head around how the framework works and how to properly extend all these classes.

My goal is this: An `Activity` that has a `ViewPager` that cycles through five `ListFragment`s. The data being bound to each `ListFragment` is coming from a web API, which is called using an `AsyncTask`.

My problem is that whenever I switch to a new fragment, the `MyListFragment.newInstance()` is called again, which calls the `AsyncTask` every time.  I'm trying to have the `AsyncTask` called once, the first time the `ListFragment` is loaded, to cut down on the web calls and save the page state.  Eventually I want to do a "Pull down to refresh" type thing, which would mean not reloading the data when I switch a page.

I've been following [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) guide on Android Developers to try to make this happen.  What I ended up with is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    MyPagerAdapter mMyPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMyPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyPagerAdapter);
    }


    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }   

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return MyListFragment.newInstance(getPageTitle(i).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { 
            String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.thing_sort_titles);
            return titles[position];
        }

    }


    public static class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
        public static final String ARG_CATEGORY = "category_title";
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;

        public MyListFragment() {
            mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            URI url = new URI("http://api.remotesite.com/" + args.getString(ARG_CATEGORY));
            new MyListAsyncTask().execute(url);
        }

        static MyListFragment newInstance(String category) {
            MyListFragment f = new MyListFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_CATEGORY, category);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        private class MyListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URI, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(URI... uris) {
                try {
                    JSONArray json = JSON.getJSONfromURL(uris[0]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i)
                        map.put("title", obj.getString("title"));
                        map.put("author", obj.getString("author"));
                        map.put("id", obj.getString("id"));
                        mylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                return mylist;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), 
                    mylist,
                    R.layout.list_item, 
                    new String[] { "title", "author" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.text_title, R.id.text_author }
                );
                MyListFragment.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing an array of `ListFragment`s in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and only call `MyListFragment.newInstance` if that index was null, but it didn't end up changing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use [**`setOffscreenPageLimit`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) to resolve your issue.
If you use it it will cache your fragment and it would not be called again.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue.  I used `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUM_PAGES)`.  The app loaded all 5 pages once at the beginning and didn't load them after that.  Now to refresh a single `Fragment`...

Comment: remember that although it's a valid solution for your scenario, if NUM_PAGES were a bigger number you might face memory and startup time issues.

Comment: Agreed.  The documentation says it's safe for a "small" number of pages (3-4).  I will always have 5 pages (for this app) so I figured it would be alright.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you use the Loaders (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) for your case.

The loaders are quite clever on that regard that it automatically deliver back to the calling component the same data as before if you use the same ID.

for example:

Fragment position 0 calls `initLoader(0, null, this);` then Fragment position 1 calls `initLoader(1, null, this);` and so on....

that way whenever `initLoader(1` << id is called the second (3rd, 4th) time, it will not execute the web call and directly deliver the same result that was delivered on the 1st call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll look into Loaders and see if they fit as well.